# Нужны ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Это, в частности, Hastelloy C276 (наш аналог ХН65МВУ) и Hastelloy C22 (прямого аналога нет).

Answer (score 1):

Запятые нужны, вводное слово обособляется.  Приводятся частные примеры (это не присоединительный союз для уточняющих членов и не наречие).

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я так и хотела - обособить.